# the adjacent sibling selector is not working on my mark up

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have used the following HTML and CSS codes:

```css
p.head-1 {
    font-size:250%;
    color:#696969;
}

p.head-2 {
    font-size:100%;
}

p.head-1+p.head-2 {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <p class="head-1">
    This is main heading
    </p>
    <p class="head-2">
    this is another header component
    </p>
</div>
```

but despite of using the sibling selector only head-2 is accepting CSS properties while head-1 remains in-effected 
`ie`  the 'text-align' property is only accepted by the `head-2` class but not by the `head-1`

Comment: Im confused... you just need `,` not `+`.

Comment: `a + b`: apply these properties to a `b` that is after an `a`. see also: [Adjacent sibling selectors - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply wrap your css like this:

```
#header p{
  font-size:250%;
  color:#696969;
  text-align: center;
  /*display:block -- not needed as p is block level element by default*/
}
```

Or, using more complex selector:

```
p[class^="head"]{
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

If you want to combine the selector then use a comma not plus operator (plus operator is used for next sibling):

```
p.head-1, p.head-2
{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the Adjacent sibling selector.

What it does, and did successfully in your case, is to identify an element which is adjacent to another.

In your example it would identify `head-2` only if it is adjacent to `head-1`. But `head-1` itself is not included.